# Rejected by App Store because of In-App Purchase

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

My app was rejected by App Store, and I received this message:

> We noticed that your app contains a payment mechanism other than in-app purchase for digital content or to unlock features or functionality within your app, which is not appropriate for the App Store. In-app purchase is the only valid in-app payment mechanism for digital content.
>
> Note: Continuing to hide functionality within your app or other dishonest acts may result in the removal of your apps from the App Store and termination of your Apple Developer Program membership and all associated memberships.
>
> Next Steps
>
> To resolve this issue, please remove all external or third-party payment mechanisms and implement in-app purchase to facilitate digital good transactions, including unlocking features or functionality within your app.
>
> If you believe your use of an alternative payment mechanism is a permissible use case, please respond directly to this message in Resolution Center with detailed information.

I am sure that I had remove all third-party payment features. Are there somebody met this problem before? Could you give me some advices? Thanks.

Comment: Have you removed all third-party payment features already after you received the message, or before it?

Comment: I have removed all 3rd-party payment features before received this.

Comment: Why not ask the reviewer for the steps that they took that they believe resulted in an external payment?  Note that even opening a web page from your app where that web page contains external payment facilities may count.

Answer (score 2):

1. Remove any external sdks or frameworks that enable payments. (Even if you are not using them)
2. Only show webviews with contents that do not allow the user to "navigate away", for instance if theres a link at the website that you are displaying that will let the user go to the "PC Version" then your app will be rejected.
3. If you can't find the reason, you are allowed to ask the reviewer for more details in reproducing the issue.
4. If you definitively believe this is a mistake, you can appeal to the review result.